# Search a phrase using Spotlight

Tags: macos, spotlight

I find Spotlight very very useful, however I would like to be able to search for documents that contain a given phrase, i.e. words appearing together, instead of anywhere in a document. Do you know of any way or plugin to perform such a search?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Mac OS X 10.5 Help](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/15155.html)

> Use quotation marks around text to
>   search for exact phrases — the same
>   way you do with most Internet
>   searches. For example, enter “trip to
>   France” in the search field to find
>   items on your computer that contain
>   that exact phrase. If you didn't use
>   quotes, the search results would
>   include items that contain any of
>   those words.

Comment: I remembered that, however for a previous version of Mac OS X it was for searching only within file names. Now it is like you said.

Comment: Broken link. :(